# LaTeX and R bundle?

Tags: r, latex, tex, knitr

I am using R to analyse statistical data and plot histograms, scatter plots etc.

And then I have to export all plots as PDFs to manually include them in LaTeX report.

I wonder if there is any way for simplification of this process?

I would be happy to write something like:

```
\chapter{One}
\begin{r}
    qplot(...)
\end{r}
```

So that the code between `\begin{r}` and `\end{r}` would generate a plot, save it somewhere as PDF and produce `TeX` like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=1\textheight]{/path/to/plot.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/).

The website has [lots of examples](http://yihui.name/knitr/demos)

within your document you can do something like

```
<<boring-plots, fig.width=4, fig.height=4, out.width='.4\\linewidth'>>=
## two plots side by side (option fig.show='hold')
par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3,las=1)
boxplot(x)
hist(x,main='')
@
```

Or even set it up so your

```
\begin{r}

\end{r}
```

syntax would work.

The [pdf output](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-minimal.pdf) of the [minimal example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) from  which the example above comes

Comment: Thank you! How could I not know about this before!

Comment: Thanks! You guys are fast. I'm glad that I'll be able to stay away from SO and focus on my knitr book instead :)

Answer (score 10):

See if you can be convinced by the 5-min [video](http://www.screenr.com/qcv8) on `knitr`'s homepage: http://yihui.name/knitr/ If you only care about LaTeX, start from 2:54.

Your source code would be like this:

```
\chapter{One}
<<plot, out.width='1\textwidth', out.height='1\textheight', fig.pos='!ht', fig.cap='your caption'>>=
    qplot(...)
@
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks very neat.

Answer (score 5):

Rstudio +knitr      are great

```
http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/overview
```